# Using Intent class in unit tests

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-studio, testing

Is it possible to create and use `Intent` class in unit tests? (not instrumentation). `Android Studio` behaves really strange, during test running it's allowed to create instance of `Intent` but in `IDE` it looks like `null` class without fields:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Intent instance that you are talking about is null because it is just a **Test Double** that the Android Gradle plugin provides when running Unit Tests. As it is not an instrumentation test, the actual Android framework is not running during the unit tests. It is all better explained here:

https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html#mocking-dependencies

You should probably Mock the Intent class and tell it what values to provide under what circumstances. There are several ways of doing this:

- Extending the Intent class in your test code and define a custom behaviour for your tests.
- Using Robolectric http://robolectric.org/ + Mockito http://mockito.org/